# Update state with spread operator

Tags: reactjs, state

I want to update state (without hooks):

```
class Table extends React.Component {
   
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
        players: [
           { number: null, points: null }
           ]
     }
  }
```

I've tried this code:

```
onAddOneClick = () => {
    this.setState = (state) => {
     ...state, number: this.state.number,
     ...state, points: state.players.points + 1
    }
```

but keep getting error:

[image]

Comment: An arrow function returning an object needs *parentheses*, `() => ({ ... })`, but there are other errors: your second `...state` might override `number` again, and you need to **call** `setState`.

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe:-) the parentheses solved some of my problems, but now I seems to have problem with this

Answer (score 0):

To return an object directly from an arrow function, you need to wrap the curly braces in parenthesis, like this:

```
this.setState((state) => ({
 ...state, 
points: state.players.points + 1
}))
```

Note that you dont need to spread the state twice.
Edit: you should also pass your arrow function as parameter to the setState call

Comment: Thanks for your time and knowledge:) Two questions: 1) I want to update both number and points.  2) how do I pass the arrow function as parameter to the setState call?

Comment: 1) you can, just add to the object returned by the arrow function:

`this.setState((state) => ({
 ...state, 
points: state.players.points + 1,
number: <new_value>
}))`

Remember that the "state" param of the arrow function represents the previous state.

2) I edited my answer showing it =)

Comment: of course, how stupid of me arrow func: setState(() => {})